# How can I find all matches of '{{**** *** **}}' with a regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to extend PHP Markdown to allow the use of {{ and }} around some parts of the text (they will become search keywords, like a tag).

I have this basic regex that kinda works:

```
preg_match_all("/\{\{(.*)\}\}/", $description, $nomsTags);
```

Except it doesn't work when there are 2 *keywords* in the same sentence:

```
This {{is}} just an {{example}}.
```

It returns '`{{is}} just an {{example}}`' instead of '`{{is}}`' and '`{{example}}`'.

How can I modify the regex so it works in both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantifiers are greedy. That means the preceeding expression is expanded to the maximum of possible repetitions. Try a non-greedy quantifier instead by appending a `?` to the quantifier:

```
/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'll accept your answer since it's only 1 character added (I'm lazy ;)) and you put an extra explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of . you could use `[^}]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/{{([^}]*)}}/", $description, $nomsTags);
```